# IPyvuetify: Adding Cards inside DataTable

Tags: vuetify.js, ipyvuetify

I am creating a data table using IPyvuetify and want to display the values in one of the columns as cards.

Looking at the vuetify docs for data table, there doesn't seem to be a clear way to do this.

Has anyone had success trying to do this in Ipyvuetify?

Thanks!